# Excel formula to calculate contribution

Tags: excel, formula

I need to calculate the error contribution by each Part_No for me to identify the top 100 Part_Nos that contribute to the total error. I need an excel formula that I can put in column F on the image below.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UXj2.jpg)

The image provided is to illustrate the scenario. My data set contains over 30,000 records that I need to pick the top 100 parts.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could get same accuracy for multiple parts Number. So exact hundred you may not be able to get. However top hundred that you can filter. use the following formula.

```
=RANK(accuracy,$E:$E,1)
```

The above ranking is based on the accuracy column. However if you want to rank based on the error contribution column. You need to remove the abs function in the error formula and use the below formula in F column.

```
=RANK(error,$D:$D,1)
```

Please note that these formulas are given with the same context that you used in your image. You need to replace the 'error' or 'accuracy' with the current row's cell detail (like 'D2' or 'E2' etc)

Comment: OZriz, please accept the answer if this solves your query.